# Trying to set JAVA_HOME for a ControlTier Installation on a VirtualBOX install of Solaris 10 (AMD) gets me a: JAVA_HOME not set or set incorrectly

Tags: java, java-home

I have googled like a crazed idiot and am slowly losing my will to live here :) The problem is, that I need to set up ControlTier and for that I need an installation of JRE and JDK (version 6u26 and 6u34) I have got them both set up and have been for the last few hours trying in vain to find out how to set the JAVA_HOME variable and according to other sites, the PATH variable in such a way that the install.sh script that is in the setup zip file for controlTier won't keep giving me a: JAVA_HOME not set or set incorrectly all the time.

I've tried allsorts of combinations of the two. Can someone please help me and point out what I have to do to get this thing spinning... It would be very much appreciated, this is really depressing. I would like to be able to get this thing running.

Cheers!

Comment: First: What have you tried? Second: The JDK includes a JRE, so it's strange having different versions of both installed.